# How to get current value on keypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue.js and creating a table inside table I ahve an input field as `quantity` so when I am typing first word it is printing `empty` on console

Supose I am typing 3 then is shows empty and if I am typing 44 then it prints 4, I am capturing the event using `v-on:keypress` I don't know what is wrong here

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {

    invoice_products: [{
      product_no: '',
      product_name: '',
      product_price: '',
      product_qty: '',
      line_total: 0
    }]
  },

  methods: {
    calculateLineTotal(invoice_product) {
      console.log(invoice_product.product_qty)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>Quantity</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(invoice_product, k) in invoice_products" :key="k">

        <td>
          <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".01" v-model="invoice_product.product_qty" v-on:keypress="calculateLineTotal(invoice_product)" />
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the event `keyup` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `keyup` event handler.

`KeyPress`, `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` are analogous to, respectively: `Click`, `MouseUp,` and `MouseDown`.

1. `Down` happens first
2. `Press` happens second (when text is entered)
3. `Up` happens last (when text input is complete).

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {

    invoice_products: [{
      product_no: '',
      product_name: '',
      product_price: '',
      product_qty: '',
      line_total: 0
    }]
  },

  methods: {
    calculateLineTotal(invoice_product) {
      console.log(invoice_product.product_qty)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>Quantity</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(invoice_product, k) in invoice_products" :key="k">

        <td>
          <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".01" v-model="invoice_product.product_qty" v-on:keyup="calculateLineTotal(invoice_product)" />
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the on `keypress` event is fired when the key is pressed, before being processed in the input field; the reason being to allow your event process function to capture it and eventually filter it off. That's why the field does not yet show the correct result, as it has not "seen" the key yet.

So, the solution you need is to change your logic to capture the `keyup` event that will be fired once the key has been input in the focused field.